# Controlling order of javascript execution PayPal Objects

Tags: javascript, execution, queuing

I have a wordpress page. I have a number of links which go to PayPalObjects. PayPalObjects requires that you put code in the footer of the page with triggers to IDs for the  elements which trigger a purchase. eg...

```
<a id="buysong_4" target="PPDGFrame" title="Click here to buy this  song now.">$</a>
```

...and then in the footer of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var embeddedPPFlow1 = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlow( {trigger : 'buysong_1'});

function MyEmbeddedFlow(embeddedFlow) {
    this.embeddedPPObj = embeddedFlow;
    this.paymentSuccess = function() {
        this.embeddedPPObj.closeFlow();
        window.location.href = "http://whatever.com/success/";
    };
    this.paymentCanceled = function() {
        this.embeddedPPObj.closeFlow();
        top.location.href = "http://whatever.com/fail/";

    };

}
var myEmbeddedPaymentFlow1 = new MyEmbeddedFlow(embeddedPPFlow1);
</script>
```

Now, since I have dozens of such links, I wanted to avoid hard coding these ids into the content. eg...

```
<a class="buysong" target="PPDGFrame" title="Click here to buy this song now.">$</a>
```

So I added the following jQuery:

```
jQuery('.buysong').each(function(index, element) {
        jQuery(this).attr('id', 'buysong_' + (index+1) );
   });
```

The rendered page correctly adds the ID attribute to each link, BUT the PayPal js does not trigger properly. IOW: I have to 'hardcode' the ids into the page. This makes me think that the jQuery is firing -after- the PayPal script.

So... how do I 'tell' the PayPalObjects script to only execute -after- the jQuery has assigned the IDs? OR... even if I accomplished that, would it -still- not work because assigning the ID attr. dynamically isn't reliable for what I want to do?

TIA,

---JC

Comment: Did you have any success with this?

Comment: I am switching to Stripe.